# QThread::terminate vs kill

Tags: c++, qt, kill, qthread, qprocess

I have a BASH script run (QProcess blocking) in a QThread (in C++).  This BASH script tars lots of files and can run for 1/2 hour.

In case the user wants to shutdown my program I need to kill my BASH script.  But how?  QThread::Quit will wait for the BASH program to terminate before processing signals, QThread::Terminate documentation says it MAY kill a thread immediately.

I want the equivalent of 'kill -9 myscript'.  Is there a proper Qt way to do this?

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the code but I suspect you'd be better off running the `bash` script via a non-blocking `QProcess` (using signals/slots to keep track of state changes) and then use [`QProcess::terminate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#terminate) or [`QProcess::kill`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#kill) if you need to terminate the process forcibly.  I think the `QThread` is just getting in the way here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not use additional threads. It's never necessary.
2. Never use any `waitForXxx` methods.
3. Use `QProcess::kill` to kill the process.
4. Use `QProcess`'s signals to get notified when the process changes state, e.g. is finished.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the equivalent of 'kill -9 myscript'. Is there a proper Qt way
>   to do this ?

from the Qt's doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#kill :

> void QProcess::kill()
>
> Kills the current process, causing it to exit immediately.
>
> On Windows, kill() uses TerminateProcess, and on Unix and macOS, the
>   **SIGKILL** signal is sent to the process.